# Agrupar Mês de acordo com Between

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Criei uma instrução em MySQL para exibir um relatório gráfico, queria que os meses fossem exibidos a partir do mês informado pela data inicial até o mês da data final. Mas no meu *SELECT* ele agrupa os meses e traz em uma ordem crescente

Instrução Sql

```
SELECT 
  MONTH(P.data_venda) as Meses, 
  SUM(P.vlr_tot_liquido) as Faturamento, 
  SUM(P.custo_total) as Custos, 
  SUM(P.vlr_tot_liquido) - SUM(P.custo_total) as Lucro 
  FROM pedido P
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT Min(pedido) as formapag_rec,
  empresa, filial, pedido, 
  plano as formapag_plano 
  FROM formapag
  WHERE empresa = 1
  GROUP BY 
  empresa, filial, pedido) 
  F ON F.empresa = P.empresa 
  and F.filial = P.filial 
  and F.pedido = P.pedido
LEFT JOIN 
   plano on plano.plano = formapag_plano
WHERE P.empresa = 1 
  AND P.data_venda BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2016-04-01' 
  AND P.vlr_tot_liquido > 0
  AND P.status = 'FIN' 
  AND (plano.especie <> 'MOV' OR plano.especie is null)
GROUP BY Meses
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu informo um mês de um ano passado até um mês de outro ano mais recente, meu resultado é tido desta forma: os primeiros meses do outro ano vindo na frente dos últimos meses do ano anterior.

Gostaria que fosse exibido **Meses : 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4** seguindo uma sequência.

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente você precisa adicionar o ano ao agrupamento (para casos onde sua consulta traga um intervalo maior que um ano, assim os valores serão específicos de cada mês/ano) e à ordenação (para que a ordem de exibição seja do mês mais antigo para o mais atual):

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(P.data_venda) as Anos, 
  MONTH(P.data_venda) as Meses, 
  SUM(P.vlr_tot_liquido) as Faturamento, 
  SUM(P.custo_total) as Custos, 
  SUM(P.vlr_tot_liquido) - SUM(P.custo_total) as Lucro 
  FROM pedido P
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT Min(pedido) as formapag_rec,
  empresa, filial, pedido, 
  plano as formapag_plano 
  FROM formapag
  WHERE empresa = 1
  GROUP BY 
  empresa, filial, pedido) 
  F ON F.empresa = P.empresa 
  and F.filial = P.filial 
  and F.pedido = P.pedido
LEFT JOIN 
   plano on plano.plano = formapag_plano
WHERE P.empresa = 1 
  AND P.data_venda BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2016-04-01' 
  AND P.vlr_tot_liquido > 0
  AND P.status = 'FIN' 
  AND (plano.especie <> 'MOV' OR plano.especie is null)
GROUP BY Anos, Meses
ORDER BY Anos, Meses
```

Repare que adicionei a coluna `Anos` para que seja exibido também o ano daquele mês.

Comment: putz cara como não pensei nisso antes rsrs obrigado por compartilhar da sua sabedoria comigo. sanou minha dúvida